# python string strip not striping newline

Tags: python, strip

I am not able to strip the space and newlines. Any idea what might gone wrong?

```
    line_count = 0
    word_count = 0

    for fline in fh:
        line = repr(fline)
        line = line.strip()
        print line
        line_count += 1
        word_count += len(line.split())

    result['size'] = filesize
    result['line'] = line_count
    result['words'] = word_count
```

output

```
'value of $input if it is\n'
' larger than or equal to ygjhg\n'
' that number. Otherwise assigns the value of \n'
' \n'
' '
```

Comment: why are you using `repr` here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your strings are surrounded by double quotes because of `repr()`:

```
>>> x = 'hello\n'
>>> repr(x)
"'hello\\n'"
>>> repr(x).strip()
"'hello\\n'"
>>>
```

Here is your edited code:

```
line_count = 0
word_count = 0

for fline in fh:
    line = repr(line.strip())
    print line
    line_count += 1
    word_count += len(line.split())

result['size'] = filesize
result['line'] = line_count
result['words'] = word_count
```

Answer (score 1):

If `fline` is a string, then calling `repr` with it as the argument would enclose it in literal quotes. Thus:

```
foo\n
```

becomes

```
"foo\n"
```

Since the newline isn't at the end of the string anymore, `strip` won't remove it. Maybe consider not calling `repr` unless you desperately need to, or calling it *after* calling `strip`.

Answer (score 1):

From what the others have mentioned, just change

```
    line = repr(fline)
    line = line.strip()
```

to

```
    line = line.strip()
    line = repr(fline)
```

Note that you might be wanting `.rstrip()` or even `.rstrip("\n")` instead.